# Right square bracket in symlist

Tags: tables, brackets

I am trying to produce a symlist with [xy] in the left hand column.  If I use `\item[$(xy)$]`, I get `(xy)` in the left column but if I want `[xy]` and use `\item[$[xy]$]` I get an error message

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
```

I understand the issue is that TeX is reading the first `]` as the ending of the argument.  On stackexchange, I found one suggestion to use the package `\usepackage{xparse}` but that didn't help or a fix for dealing with ones own macros, but I am dealing with the built-in symlist (although I'm not sure where it is coming from!)!

Ideally, I'd like a primitive like `\lbrac` but that doesn't exist.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Your comment about a built-in symlist are cryptic, but doing in thus `item[{[$xy$]}] ` solves the issue

Comment: Are you sure you want `itemize` instead of `description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally, I'd like a primitive like `\lbrac` but that doesn't exist.

I can think of two fixes; the first one has already been mentioned by @yannisl in a comment:

- `\item[{$[xy]$}]`
- `\item[$\lbrack xy\rbrack$]`

`\lbrac` doesn't exist, but `\lbrack` does. :-)

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}

\item[{$[xy]$}] \dots

\item[$\lbrack uv\rbrack$] \dots

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```